# Can I rebound a spell that exiles itself?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

There's a handful of cards from the game [which also exile themselves as they resolve](https://scryfall.com/search?q=%28t%3Ainstant+or+t%3Asorcery%29+o%3A%22exile+~.%22&order=set). For a straightforward example there's [Restock](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRestock%5d):

> Return two target cards from your graveyard to your hand. Exile Restock.

That's fine enough. But what if I have [Cast Through Time](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCast%20Through%20Time%5d) on the battlefield to give it rebound?

> Instant and sorcery spells you control have rebound. *(Exile the spell as it resolves if you cast it from your hand. At the beginning of your next upkeep, you may cast that card from exile without paying its mana cost.)*

**Will Restock rebound out of exile?**

There doesn't seem to be a ruling about this on Cast Through Time. The one part I'm confident about is that if it does rebound, it won't rebound a second time -- it'll exile itself again and it won't have been cast from my hand that time.

Comment: Interesting note about Rebound: when a spell is cast from exile with rebound, it goes to the graveyard. If the spell in exile is not casted, then it stays in exile. So it doesn't exile itself again when cast from exile

Comment: @Mart10 That's right; Rebound only functions on cards that were cast out of your hand, so e.g. it doesn't work on cards that have been cast with Flashback either (since they were cast from your graveyard).

Comment: This part in your question is wrong then: "if it does rebound, it won't rebound a second time -- it'll exile itself again" It will not exile, it will go to graveyard

Comment: @Mart10 If the spell exiles itself off the stack as part of its own resolution, it won't still be around to be put into the graveyard afterwards.

Comment: if you're referring to Restock specifically then you're right (although it wont have the rebound effect in the first place according to answers)

Comment: @Mart10 I'm referring to any spell that says "Exile (this spell)." as part of its effect, so I think they'd all behave like Restock.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**No, spells that exile themselves will not rebound.**

This is supported by the definition of Rebound in the comprehensive rules: (emphasis mine)

> **702.87a** Rebound appears on some instants and sorceries. It represents a static ability that functions while the spell is on the stack and may create a delayed triggered ability. “Rebound” means “If this spell was cast from your hand, ***instead of putting it into your graveyard as it resolves***, exile it and, at the beginning of your next upkeep, you may cast this card from exile without paying its mana cost.”

Rebound works by putting the card into exile *instead* of putting it into your graveyard after the spell is finished resolving. A card that exiles itself never goes into the graveyard, so Rebound dosen't have a chance to move it, and give you the chance to cast it for free at your next upkeep.

Comment: Exactly. One shouldn't rely on the reminder since it's a simplified version of abilities that doesn't cover corner cases. Looking at the actual definition make the answer obvious in this and many other cases.

Comment: @ikegami Thanks for the edit to make the answer stand on its own, I modified it to be a bit more in my usual writing style.

Answer (score 10):

According to several sources (see below), you won't get to cast it again. I'm quoting an explanation very fitting from [Cranial Insertion](http://www.cranialinsertion.com/article/1269):

> It won't rebound. Rebound works by replacing the normal process of going to the graveyard after the spell is done resolving with exiling and setting up a delayed trigger. But that never happens with spells that exile themselves, because they do their exiling as part of resolving them. The spell never gets to the point where the game would try to put it into the graveyard, so the rebound never happens.
>
> The important thing to understand with both rebound and unearth isn't really where the card is going. What's important is what's putting it there. The rebounded spell doesn't come back because what's putting it in exile is the spell's own exile-it-forever effect. A flickered unearth creature will come back because what's putting it in exile is the flicker's exile-and-bring-it-back effect.

In that sense, it appears that the ruling on [Cast Through Time](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCast%20Through%20Time%5d) quoted in the question doesn't apply to "zone other than exile", but "zone other than the graveyard".

Other sources:

- [tappedout.net](http://tappedout.net/mtg-questions/rebound-on-cards-that-exile-themselves/)
- [Matt Tabak's Twitter](https://twitter.com/TabakRules/status/573203747322503168?s=17): "So yes, you can technically give [Temporal Trespass](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTemporal%20Trespass%5d) rebound, but it won't work."

Comment: I could be wrong here, but since a spell can be exiled from any zone (see 406.7), wouldn't that mean rebound would still trigger, because the spell still resolves? Or does exiling prevent resolving from occurring?

Comment: My thinking is that it would, and that's why they put in the ruling about it (see answer from Mart10, or the Cast Through Time rulings http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=198301) That makes this answer and that post incorrect. The spell still resolves, so rebound would still be triggered, but wizards ruled that it was too strong =P

Comment: I was wrong, there is another reason it doesn't work. See the other answer for both reasons

Answer (score 5):

**No**

Ruling from [mtg Gamepedia](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Rebound):

> If a spell moves itself into another zone as part of its resolution
>   (as Arc Blade, All Suns' Dawn, and Beacon of Unrest do), rebound won't
>   get a chance to apply

Moreover, the card exiling itself is part of the resolution, so [Cast Through Time](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2B%5BCast%20Through%20Time%5D) will no longer be giving it Rebound when Rebound would trigger, as the card is already exiled.

Comment: From mackenzie's edit, I realize that  Cast Through Time requires you to control the spell for it to have rebound, and you do not control it once it is exiled

Comment: That's why I edited it, I didn't understand what you meant by it at first haha. Hopefully it's more clear now. If you have a better way to phrase it feel free to edit it again =)

Comment: @MackenzieMcClane What I meant is that the fact that the spell exiles itself before Rebound triggers wont give it any chance to trigger (see the ruling i cited)

Comment: Yea, we're on the same page haha